Bailey and Hamilton's Law of Varying Action
Starting in the early 1970s and continuing for more than twenty years Bailey with his students published a series of articles on  the application of what they called Hamilton's Law of Varying Action (HLVA); see, below a short list of those. To say that their work was mercilessly attacked by many for alleged lack of historical accuracy, errors in logic, errors in basic variational concepts, errors in mathematical analysis, etc., would understate the critics' message. One quite detailed attack was by Papastavridis who himself has written a 1,400+ (yes!) pages long treatise on variational mechanics.
I am not interested in the historical originality of Bailey's work or whether he understands the role of Hamilton-Jacobi transformations (I don't...), etc. My question is really about the engineering aspect (in a broad sense) of what he was proposing, and what I believe was actually ignored by his critics. Below is my short view of Bailey's method and I ask the experts here to opine on its meaning.
Let $\mathcal F = F(\{x_i\},\{v_i\},t)$ with $i=1,2,..,n,$ be a continuous differentiable function of $2n+1$ variables and let $\eta_i = \eta_i (t)$ be also a set of continuous differentiable functions of time but otherwise arbitrary .
Now fix $t_0 < t_1$ and form the integral
$$ \mathcal A[\mathcal F(x)] =\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt F(\{x_i\},\{\dot x_i\},t) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Let $\epsilon >0$ and calculate the difference
$$ \mathcal A[F(x+\epsilon \eta, \dot x +\epsilon \dot \eta, t)]-\mathcal A[ F(x, \dot x, t)]
=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left(F(x+\epsilon \eta, \dot x +\epsilon \dot \eta, t)]- F(x, \dot x, t)\right)dt\\
=\epsilon \int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\sum_i\left[\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial x_i}\eta_i +\left. \frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v_i}\right|_{v_i=\dot x_i}^{} \dot \eta_i\right] +\mathcal O(\epsilon^2)\\
=\epsilon\sum_i\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left[\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial x_i}\eta_i + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\left. \frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v_i}\right|_{v_i=\dot x_i}  \eta_i\right) - \frac{d}{dt}\left( \left. \frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v_i}\right|_{v_i=\dot x_i} \right) \eta_i \right]+\mathcal O(\epsilon^2)\tag{2}\label{2}$$
and then with suppressing the indices for better readability and the summations be understood implicitly,
$$\left. \frac{d\mathcal A}{d\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0}=\sum_i\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left[ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\left.\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v_i}\right|_{v_i=\dot x_i}  \eta_i\right)  \right]
+\sum_i\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left[ \frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial x_i}\eta_i  - \frac{d}{dt}\left( \left.\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v_i}\right|_{v_i=\dot x_i} \right) \eta_i \right]\\
=\left[\left. \frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v}\right|_{v=\dot x}  \eta_i\right]_{t_0}^{t_1}
+\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left[\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial x}- \frac{d}{dt}\left( \left.\frac{\partial F(x, v, t)}{\partial v}\right|_{v=\dot x} \right)  \right]\eta\tag{4}\label{4}.$$
Combining $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{4}$ and writing $v=\dot x$ for short, we get
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt \left[\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial x}\eta + \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x} \dot \eta\right] -
\left[ \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x}  \eta\right]_{t_0}^{t_1}=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt\left[\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial x}- \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x} \right)  \right]\eta\tag{5}\label{5},$$
This Equation $\eqref {5}$ is called Hamilton's Law of Varying Action, it can be found in Hamilton's 1835 memoir and nothing in this derivation is controversial so far.
Now let $t_0=0$ for short and Bailey sets the lower variation be zero, $\eta_i(0)=0$ or $\eta(0)=0,$ for all coordinates. I also write $\tau$ for the dummy integration variable and $t$ for the upper limit end-time.
$$\int_{0}^{t}d\tau \left[\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial x}\eta + \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial \dot x} \dot \eta\right] -
\left[\left. \frac{ \partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x}  \eta\right]\right|_t=\int_{0}^{t}d\tau\left[\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial x}- \frac{d}{d\tau}\left( \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial \dot x} \right)  \right]\eta\tag{6}\label{6}$$
This $\eqref{6}$ is actually an identity, there is no physics involved here so far, just summation, partial derivatives and integration, etc. Being completely general it must also hold when the Euler-Lagrange equations hold and that is when physics comes in; specifically, when we demand that the expression having the Euler-Lagrange operand be zero in the bracket of the RHS integral; that is when the true trajectory $x_i(t)$, $i=1,2,..n,$ satisfies for a given $F=F(x,\dot x, t)$ a system of $n$ simultaneous second order differential equations:
$$\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial x_i} - \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x_i, t)}{\partial \dot x_i} \right)=0.\\i=1,2,...,n \tag{EL}\label{EL}$$
Now Bailey says that because of the arbitrariness of $\eta$ we can "solve" this set of $\eqref{EL}$ equations both analytically and algebraically in a successive approximation scheme by ensuring that the left hand side of $\eqref {6}$ be zero. He proposes that we use a set of arbitrary differentiable functions $X_i$ of time $t$ with a set of "variational" parameters $a=a_1,a_2,..,a_m,.....$ and write in the $m^{th}$ approximation step $x_i(t) = X_i(t;a_1,a_2,.., a_m)$ and our job now is to find that particular set of $a=\{a_k\}$ with which
$$\int_{0}^{t}d\tau \left[\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial x}\eta + \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial \dot x} \dot \eta\right] -
 \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x}  \eta(t) = 0\tag{7}\label{7}.$$
Since the time function is given $x_i=X_i(t;a)$ we have the variation of $x_i$ that is $\eta_i= \sum_k \frac{\partial X_i}{\partial a_k}\delta a_k$ and that of $\dot x_i$ as $\dot \eta_i= \sum_k \frac{\partial \dot X_i}{\partial a_k}\delta a_k$, resp., resulting in Bailey's equation:
$$\left[\int_{0}^{t}d\tau \left(\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial X}{\partial a}\ + \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial \dot x} \frac{\partial \dot X}{\partial a}\right) - \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x} \frac{\partial X}{\partial a}\right]\delta a = 0 \tag{8}\label{8}.$$
As the variations $\delta a_k$ are independent of each other and for a given $t$ fixing the upper limit of integration we get a set of algebraic equations to be solved for the unknown $a_k$ parameters. Let us write this out explicitly in index notation:
$$\sum_i\int_{0}^{t}d\tau \left(\frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial X_i}{\partial a_k}\ + \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, \tau)}{\partial \dot x_i} \frac{\partial \dot X_i}{\partial a_k}\right) =
\sum_i \frac{\partial F(x, \dot x, t)}{\partial \dot x_i} \frac{\partial X_i}{\partial a_k}\\
k=1,2,...,m
\tag{9}\label{9}.$$
We can force the initial coordinates at $t=0$ to be $x_i(0)=x_i^0$ by setting our trial functions in the form $x_i(t)=x_i^0+tX_i(t;a)$, or with initial velocities $\dot x_i(0)=\dot x_i^0$ as $x_i(t)=x_i^0+ \dot x_i^0t+X_i(t;a)t^2$, etc. Not just differential, but other type of constraints can be enforced, as well.
In $\eqref{9}$ we are given the functions $F(x,v,t)$ and $ X_i(t;a_1,a_2,..a_m)$ and only the parameters $\{a_k\}$ are unknown. Once the integrations are done with the unknow parameters both sides are just functions of the parameters $\{a_k\}$ and thus we have a system of $m$ equations of exactly the same number of unknowns $m$. As $m$ increases the solution $\{a_k^*\}$ of this system of algebraic equations in the limit is the one that provides the trajectory $x_i(t)=X_i(t; a_1^*,a_2^*,..a_m^*,...)$ that will satisfy the Euler-Lagrange equations and the prescribed initial conditions.
Thus, Bailey's method generates explicit solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equations in the limit of the successive approximation as initial value problems compatible with the prescribed forms of the trial functions. Note that Bailey and several other researchers used this method to find numerical solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equations with success.
But something is really strange about this whole idea. We set the end time $t>0$ arbitrarily and get a set of parameters $a=\{a_k\}$ from the system of algebraic equations $\eqref{9}$ that will give us the trajectory $x_i(t)=X_i(t; a)$ but then $x_i(\tau)=X_i(\tau; a)$ must also hold for all $0\le\tau \le t.$ So what happens if we pick an instant $t'>t$; shall we still have the same trajectory so that $x_i(t')=X_i(t'; a)$? We should, because at $t'=t$ they have the same $x_i(t)$ as initial conditions.
With the assumed Euler-Lagrange equations $\eqref{EL}$ to hold while setting $t$ to be an infinitesimal we just get the triviality $0=0.$ In other words, it is essential to assume that $t$ be finite and not infinitesimal and then we do get the full trajectory $x_i(t)=X_i(t; a),$ for all $t,$ but then the ${a_k}$ parameters in the limit must be related to the integral invariants of the EL equations.
Question: How are these $a_k$ parameters related to the various invariants of the trajectory?
References:

Hitzl:"Implementing Hamilton's Law of Varying Action with
Shifted Legendre Polynomials", JOURNAL OF COMPUTATIONAL PHYSICS 38,
pp185-211 (1980)
Papastavridis: "THE VARIATIONAL PRINCIPLES OF MECHANICS, AND A REPLY TO C. D. BAILEY," Journal of Sound and Vibration (1987) 118(2), pp378-393
Bailey: "A new look at Hamilton's principle," Foundations of
Physics, Vol. 5, No. 3, 1975
Bailey: "Application of Hamilton's Law of Varying Action," AIAA JOURNAL VOL. 13, NO. 9 pp1154-1157
Bailey: "FURTHER REMARKS ON THE LAW OF VARYING ACTION," Journal of Sound and Vibration (1989)  131(2), pp331-344


This feels like a silly rewriting; since you already agreed that the LHS and the RHS are exactly the same thing, i.e. an identity, then solving via RHS, i.e. solving the E-L equations, should be the same thing as solving the LHS; varying parameters to satisfy the E-L equations, should be the same thing as varying parameters to satisfy the LHS=0. So I don't see what value this adds, nor what physically interesting insights are being introduced.

Available for download: document consisting of scans of pages written with a typewriter, with the equations inserted in handwriting. Cecil D. Bailey Application of Hamilton's law of Varying Action The document has the same title as  ref. 4, but I have no way of determining whether this document is the original manuscript for the submission to the AIAA journal.

Here is my best guess, in the form of a comparison with the history of thermodynamics. When Sadi Carnot formulated his thermodynamics he was right, but not for the reasons that Sadi Carnot thought. The concept of 'Caloric' had to be abandoned, but the observations of Carnot's thermodynamics and the mathematics of Carnot's thermodynamics survived. You mention: 'Bailey and several other researchers used this method to find numerical solutions to the Euler-Lagrange equations with success' So Bailey must have done something right. However, not necessarily for the reasons that Bailey thought.

@Cleonis Bailey was the professor of Aeronautics and the reference you have found was a NASA contract forming the basis of the 1975 original publication of the same title and almost the same content as in the AIAA journal. It is also interesting that critics claimed that Bailey's scheme  is the Galerkin's expansion but that is incorrect. They do produce the same when F is quadratic and then EL are linear but not otherwise. I do not even know what Galerkin would mean for nonlinear operators; this is how stumbled on Bailey... I think the caloric as calorique is alive today as entropy.

@naturallyInconsistent A silly rewriting, you say but rewriting an equation such as $x^2−x−1=0$  into the rather silly form $x=\frac{1+x}{x}$ and then use it as iteration $x_{n+1}=\frac{1+x_n}{x_n}$ with $x_0=1$ quickly gets you to $x=1.6180...$ Or how about the even sillier looking rewriting of the same as $x=1+\frac{1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$, etc. the beginning idea of a continued fraction expansion, now that is really silly.

Well, the set of curves $x_i(t)=X_i(t; a_1^*,a_2^*,..a_m^*)$, generally speaking,  do not satisfy the EL equations (EL) contrarily to what is argued in the post (if I have correctly understood the explanation above, otherwise I apologise!).
We have the following relations.

(EL) imply (6);

equations
(6) imply (EL) only if the functional variantions $\eta$ can be arbitrarily fixed in a suitable  space of (sufficiently regular) functions such that for every neighborhood of a point in the real (temporal) line there is a non-negative, non-vanishing, function of the space whch is has support in that neighborhood. This space is therefore necessarily infinite dimensional;

in general, (9) does not imply (6) and thus also (EL). That is because, in (9), the possible variations are spanned by a finite dimensional space of functions.


The  set of curves $x_i(t)=X_i(t; a_1^*,a_2^*,..a_m^*)$ is just a solution of the algebraic equations  (9).
In general,  there is no chance to tune a finite set of arbitrary constants $a=\{a_j\}$ within a given finite set function $X_i(t,a)$ which is capable to describe all solutions of the EL equations: it is a desperate task!
At most, with a suitable choice of the functions $X_i(t,a)$ it is possible to approximate some type of solutions. And I think, this mathod should  be very efficient in this context.
So the answer to final question:
"How are these $a_k$ parameters related to the various invariants of the trajectory?"
is "They are not related".

Thank you! You are absolutely right: I left out he words "successive approximation", "in the limit", etc., and I have now added them above. For the record, Bailey did not leave this point out as I wrongly did here, after all he had used the scheme as numerical approximation that is not Galerkin's method although the two are the same for the linear case, neither does Bailey demand that the approximants be a linear sum in general. Still my question still holds: after assuming convergence as $m\to \infty$ the $a_k$ should determine the invariants as some function, right?

I am saying this because these $a_k$ are not just coefficients that are the result of, say, the mean square minimization of some expansion into shifted Legendre or Chebyshev polynomials but the kind whose variation is explicitly compatible with the EL equations. This is why I am expecting something more physical from them. Something along the lines of an equation for an invariant $I_{\ell}=g_{\ell}(a_1,a_2,a_3,....)$ where the $g_{\ell}$ follows some other variational equation of the coefficients. Or is this just a mirage?

Sorry, this approach  is really too far from my expertise. Frankly speaking I cannot say more than my superficial already posted answer.

About the content of the NASA document (where Bailey was professor of Aeronautics), that forms the basis of the 1975 original publication of the same title: Application of Hamilton's law of Varying Action

A quote from page 6:

Note that the zero on the right hand side of eq. 4 results from the fact that nature requires the equations of equilibrium to vanish as observed by Newton. It has nothing to do with the proof in variational calculus that the integral is an extremum.

Quote from page 13

$t_i$ is arbitrary. However, it is kept relatively small with the understanding that a longer period of time can be examined simply by taking the final conditions as calculated for one interval as the initial conditions of the next interval. It should be emphasized that the number of terms required in the truncated power series is not the important criteria from a practical viewpoint. The computer time required for solutions is the important criteria. Ten terms in the time variable have been found to be sufficient for all non-stationary problems of particles, beams, and plates treated to date. With this number of terms in the truncated power series, the computer time for every case of single degree of freedom particle motion was below the minimum amount ($1.68) charged for the computer and the accuracy, as will be shown, was far above expectation.


I think that in the 1970's the considerations of Professor Bailey were driven by the fact that his productivity was compute power constrained. Making his computations twice as efficient makes him and his team twice as productive.
As long as the accuracy of the results is within specification, with generous margin, Bailey will keep pushing for more efficiency.

About the newtonian formulation of mechanics:
The newtonian formulation of mechanics generalizes to using generalized coordinates, and extension of the concept of force to generalized force.
See: Richard Fitzpatrick, University of Texas at Austin
Generalized forces

My hypothesis as to what is going on:
Professor Bailey keeps insisting that in his numerical analysis algorithms he can totally accommodate non-conservative forces. My opinion (based on the contents of the article): the reason Bailey can accommodate non-conservative forces: his numerical integration implementations are actually according to newtonian formulation (ported to generalized coordinates). We have every reason to trust that the numerical integration algorithms were fine.
Hypothesis:
Professor Bailey has talked himself into believing that applying generalized coordinates automatically means you are applying Hamilton's principle. (Could be two-stage association: applying generalize coordinates => Lagrangian mechanics. Using Lagrangian mechanics => Hamilton's principle.)
That, I hypothesize, is the reason why professor Bailey keeps insisting that everything he does is extension of Hamilton's principle.
(With idiosyncratic notation to make the expressions similar in visual appearance to application of Hamilton's principle.)



Summery of my opinion:
What Professor Bailey was doing was numerical integration, according to  newtonian formulation, with generalized coordinates.
But at the same time Professor Bailey had convinced himself that in formal descriptions of his methodology he had to insist that he was using Hamilton's principle.

There is no difficulty with adding a nonholonomic term, such as $B_1dx_1+B_2dx_2+...$ into the left side of the HLVA action integral and the expansion follows the same scheme as described above (I have fixed in it some errors). If interested I can send you a few papers  I collected on the subject but here is an MIT thesis you can read https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/13271/25037261-MIT.pdf?sequence=2.  It appears that as a numerical scheme there are faster ones now and nothing has been written about it in the last 15 years, or so. My interest is in its meaning, if any. Thanks.

@hyportnex About meaning. The thing is: the relation between the newtonian formulation and stationary action concept is much closer than people assume it to be. About derivation: quote from physics stackexchange contributor Kevin Zhou (knzhou) 'in physics, you can often run derivations in both directions' The relation between $F=ma$ and the classical mechanics stationary action concept is an instance of that. There is a straightforward sequence from F=ma to stationary action Knowing that sequence allows you to see how close the relation is.

I agree with this interpretation but I think the HLVA is "richer" than "F=ma". Do you have any thoughts on how one could write/derive a variational equation for the dynamic invariants of the motion similar to Bailey's form of the HLVA or this idea is just a dead squirrel on the road... Anyhow, here are Hamilton's 1834 and 1835 articles in modern typeset https://emis.dsd.sztaki.hu/classics/Hamilton/GenMeth.pdf and https://emis.dsd.sztaki.hu/classics/Hamilton/SecEssay.pdf in which he introduced the law of varying action starting the 1st article with it. Thanks.

@hyportnex The modern typeset documents are the work of David R. Wilkins. There is a page with a list of all transcripts of publications by Hamilton that Wilkins made. I just traced when I first gave links (here on physics stackexchange) to the transcripts by David Wilkins: it was in a 2019 answer

@hyportnex There is the statement: 'In any logical system there is great freedom to interchange theorem and axiom without changing the content of the system'. In assessing the range from $F=ma$ to $\int_{s_0}^s F ds = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$ (Work-Energy theorem) to stationary action I submit the physics content is the same across the board. Difference is at the level of mathematical form. Analogy: any particular ellipse can be specified in cartesian coordinates or in polar coordinates. Then notations looks different, but the curve is the same.
